# Wordpress seems to be suppressing img title attribute

Tags: php, wordpress, image, title

I am using a modified version of [ContentFlow](http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/) in Wordpress 3.9.1 . ContentFlow is a coverflow tool that generates a coverflow from a series of  tags and their caption is created from the title=""-attribute.

I have a piece of php code that gets included to individual posts/pages via a template file and the insert php plugin, which runs just fine. It creates img tags that look like this:

```
<img class="item" src="http://www.path-to-the-image.com/001.jpg" href="http://www.path-to-the-image.com/001.jpg" title="001" id="" />
```

This all works fine. But when I let wordpress execute the script and render the image I get this:

```
<img class="item" src="http://www.path-to-the-image.com/001.jpg" href="http://www.path-to-the-image.com/001.jpg" id="">
```

As you can see the title tag is missing. And it seems to be specifically title tags. If I rename the title tag in php to e.g. "testtitle" I get flawlessly

```
<img class="item" src="http://www.path-to-the-image.com/001.jpg" href="http://www.path-to-the-image.com/001.jpg" testtitle="001" id="" />
```

So it seems Wordpress is suppressing the title tag by force. I have no plugins that should do this. Any ideas where the tag goes missing?

I have another installation running on the same server that does not have this issue, also running Wordpress 3.9.1

Comment: In the meantime I found a workaround for this issue, as ContentFlow allows for alternate syntax that does not require the title tag, but is less elegant to create by spreading the individual item from one img tag to an img and two divs.

Answer (score 1):

I found this on [wordpress.org](https://wordpress.org/plugins/img-title-restore/):

> ### IMG Title Restore
>
> WordPress 3.5 introduced a new feature – when images are inserted into posts, the title attribute is not included in the image tag. This was done with the best of intentions relating to accessibility, as documented on [Trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18984)
>
> Unfortunately, this causes problems for some Lightbox plugins, quite apart from stopping image tooltips from appearing.
>
> This plugin hooks into the media_send_to_editor filter and inserts the image title into the html inserted into the post.